# Combobox usercontrol SelectedItem data binding in WPF container

Tags: wpf, combobox

This is my combobox usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Hexa.Screens.UsrColorPicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hexa.Screens"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Height="40" Width="200" Name="uccolorpicker"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType"  ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,  Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"  MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox Name="superCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}" SelectedValuePath="Name"  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=uccolorpicker, Path=SelectedColor}" Text="{Binding ElementName=uccolorpicker,Path=Text}" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=uccolorpicker, Path=SelectedItem}"  SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=uccolorpicker, Path=SelectedIndex}" SelectionChanged="superCombo_SelectionChanged"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5" Background="{Binding Name}"  />
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

This is the code behind:

```
  namespace Hexa.Screens
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Interaction logic for UsrColorPicker.xaml
      /// </summary>
      public partial class UsrColorPicker : UserControl
      {
          public UsrColorPicker()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          public Brush SelectedColor
          {
              get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
              set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
          }

          public int SelectedIndex
          {
              get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
              set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
          }

          public int SelectedItem
          {
              get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
              set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
          }

          public string Text
          {
              get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedTextProperty); }
              set { SetValue(SelectedTextProperty, value); }
          }


          // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
          public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(UsrColorPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

          public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(UsrColorPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

          public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(int), typeof(UsrColorPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

          public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(int), typeof(UsrColorPicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));




          public static readonly RoutedEvent SettingConfirmedEvent =
          EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SettingConfirmedEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
          typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UsrColorPicker));

          public event RoutedEventHandler SettingConfirmed
          {
              add { AddHandler(SettingConfirmedEvent, value); }
              remove { RemoveHandler(SettingConfirmedEvent, value); }
          }

          private void superCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
          {
              RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UsrColorPicker.SettingConfirmedEvent));
          }
      }
 }
```

I am trying to set its SelectedItem,SelectedIndex thru xaml binding in my container's XAML as under:-

```
<local:UsrColorPicker x:Name="cmbItem_Group_back_color"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="205" Height="22"   SettingConfirmed="cmbItem_Group_back_color_SettingConfirmed"  SelectedColor ="{Binding Path=CurrentRec.Primary_Tone,Mode=TwoWay}"     Canvas.Left="97" Canvas.Top="92"    />
```

The code behind is as under:-

```
 form_load()
 {
 this.DataContext = DataContract_ButtonSettings;
 }
```

But the selecteditem's text is not showing on the combobox as it should.

Comment: *"this is not working"* -- kindly describe exactly what the symptoms are. And please show codebehind for your usercontrol. I can't guess whether any of your dependency properties even exist.

Comment: The selectedcolor property does not display the selectedcolor(Text) on the combobox as it is expected.It just displays blank there.

Comment: This is the code behind:

Comment: namespace Hexa.Screens
{
   
    public partial class UsrColorPicker : UserControl
    {
        public UsrColorPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Brush SelectedColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
        }

Comment: Put it in the question, please. Nobody can read that.

Comment: the site isnt letting me write the whole code...so m writiing it in chunks

Comment: namespace Hexa.Screens
{
    public partial class UsrColorPicker : UserControl
    {
        public UsrColorPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Brush SelectedColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
        }

Comment: Put the code in the question.

Comment: check here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896524/user-controls-code-behind-usercontrol-does-not-display-the-name-of-the-selected

Comment: Put the code in this question. Put it in this question. Edit this question and put the code in it.

Comment: plz check now..I have put all the code in this question itself

Comment: Delete the other question please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.It was a careless mistake..
The bug was nowhere in the code posted..Actually,i was using the usercontrol's selectedcolor property to bind to the backcolor property of an element in the view.The viewmodel updates the SelectedColor property of the ColorCombobox.The viewmodel was being updated from many places in the code behind.And at one place,the viewmodel's SelectedColor property was being set with the HEX equivalent of the known Color of System.Windows.Media.Colors Known color,and when the view model wud try to bind to that Hex element to the ComboBox,it did not find any matching entry for that Hex value in the dropdown list,and hence,though the background color of the control was being effected,the combobox text showed blank.:-).
anyways,solved it...thanks for your time Ed. :-).